# ArrayBlockingQueue (ABQ) vs LinkedBlockingQueue (LBQ): Why LBQ need AtomicInteger counter?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

ABQ uses an `int` for counting the size of the queue and it works fine.

```java
    /** Number of elements in the queue */
    int count;
```

LBQ uses `AtomicInteger` for the same purpose.

```java
    /** Current number of elements */
    private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
```

Will there be any issues if I replace the `AtomicInteger` with an `int`?

Why ArrayBlockingQueue only needs to do count++, while LinkedBlockingQueue has to do getAndDecrement?

In LBQ methods `put` / `take` / etc, `count.getAndIncrement()` is also performed with a lock held. I wonder if the reason of using AtomicInteger is because method such as `unlink` doesn't hold the lock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace it with an `int` if you perform all atomic read-modify-write operations (for example, [`getAndDecrement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndDecrement())) with `VarHandle`.

In `ArrayBlockingQueue` no atomic read-modify-write operations are performed on `count`, so an `int` suffices.
Moreover, all operations like `count++` are performed with a lock held (`lock`). Therefore they can not be performed by two threads concurrently.

`unlink()` is always called with both locks held in `LinkedBlockingQueue`. It takes a single time where `count` is incremented atomically without the same lock held, to warrant it to be incremented atomically with other locks held.

Let us look at the `take()` method:

```
// ...
final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
final ReentrantLock takeLock = this.takeLock;
takeLock.lockInterruptibly();
try {
    // ...
    c = count.getAndDecrement();
    // ...
} finally {
    takeLock.unlock();
}
// ...
```

Let us look at the `put()` method:

```
// ...
final ReentrantLock putLock = this.putLock;
final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
putLock.lockInterruptibly();
try {
    // ...
    c = count.getAndIncrement();
    // ...
} finally {
    putLock.unlock();
}
// ...
```

As you can see, in both cases `count` is incremented and decremented atomically. It could not be otherwise, because the lock held in both cases differs; in the first case, it is `takeLock`, in the second, `putLock`.

If operations on `count` were not atomic, two threads, one executing `take()`, and one executing `put()`, could create a race condition.

Comment: Then is it because of the use of `count` in methods such as `size()` and `remainingCapacity`? They `get` on `count` without holding the lock.

Comment: @YikSanChan `get()` is a volatile read, so `volatile` would have sufficed.

Comment: "It takes a single time where count is incremented atomically without the same lock held, to warrant it to be incremented atomically with other locks held." Do you mean, AtomicInteger is more of an "extra care" s.t. even if in any cases the implementation forgets to protect the `count` with lock, the implementation is still thread-safe?

Comment: @YikSanChan No, I mean exactly what happens with `LinkedBlockingQueue`. See my edit.